# Как по клику на метку на карте отобразить свою верстку

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как при клике на метку на карте yandex api, отобразить div блок?

```
myPlacemark.events.add("click", function(){

});
```

Например, показать просто блок `<div id="mydata"> </div>`

Comment: `document.querySelector('#mydata').style.display = 'block'` ?

Comment: myPlacemark.events.add("click", function(){
document.querySelector('#mydata').style.display = 'block';
});  да точно, получилось, спасибо!